# Not opening a specific text file in Python

Tags: python, text, file-io

I have a folder with a bunch of text files. I have the following code that opens all the text files in its directory when executed and throws them all together in a master text file, "result.txt".

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

I don't want this script to open "result.txt". All text files except result.txt. How can I do this? I don't want it to duplicate result.txt by writing its contents into itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `filter` function:

```
read_files = filter(lambda f : f != 'result.txt', glob.glob('*.txt'))
```

Comment: That's much better than my solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can filter result.txt when looping through all files:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in (file for file in read_files if file != "result.txt"):
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Alternatively, to prevent bugs in futher uses of `read_files` list, you could remove `"result.txt"` from it after glob.glob:

```
read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
try:
    read_files.remove("result.txt")
except ValueError: #File result.txt does not exist yet
    pass
```

Comment: Deleting it would not be most optimal for me because the text file is quite large and the script is run numerous times.

Comment: I never suggested to remove the `"result.txt"` file, but rather the corresponding string in the `read_files` list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `continue` to skip the file and start the next iteration of the loop:

```
for f in read_files:
    if f == "result.txt":
        continue
    ...
```

Alternatively, filter the list of files before you start looping:

```
read_files = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt") if f != "result.txt"]
```

Comment: *facepalm* I should have been able to think of that hehe ... thanks!